# Create a class that contains all functions of its parent class except one

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, visual-c++

Suppose I have two classes,
one is:

```
class A{
public:
    void f1()
    {
        cout << "function 1";
    }
    void f2()
    {
        cout << "function 2";
    }
    void f3()
    {
        cout << "function 3";
    }
};
```

Now I want class `B` to contain all the functions of `A` except `f3`.

what I am doing is:

```
class B: public A
{
    private:
    void f3()
    {

    }
};
```

According to my knowledge, `B::f3()` is hiding the definition of `A::f3()`, and as `B::f3()` is private, `f3()` is not accessible via class `B`. But what I can still do is call it like this:

```
B var();
var.A::f3();
```

Is there any way I could completely hide `f3` from class `B` using inheritance and without changing class `A`?

Comment: Inheritance is useful to extend, not restrict. You may want to go with composition in your case instead.

Comment: If a child class does not have all the functionality of its parent class then it probably shouldnt derive from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't get in the habit of piecing classes together through inheritance by mixing and matching classes that do roughly what you want. That leads to awful code.

However, *occasionally* it does make sense to implement one class by means of another. In those cases, if you are using inheritance, the "correct" way to do it is by using **private** inheritance.

And by "correct" I mean the most acceptable way.

```
class A
{
public:
    void f1()
    {
        cout << "function 1";
    }
    void f2()
    {
        cout << "function 2";
    }
    void f3()
    {
        cout << "function 3";
    }
};

class B: private A
{
public:
    using A::A; // use A's constructors
    using A::f1;
    using A::f2;
    // do not use f3
};
```

The times when this may make sense is when composition is way too tedious because of the number of methods involved.

Comment: Private inheritance can be thought of as meaning "implemented in terms of". Ie "class B is implemented in terms of class A". This is the exact problem private inheritance is meant to solve.

Answer (score 9):

You should **not make `B` inherit from `A`.**

If `B` lacks some functionality of `A`, then `B` and `A` do not have the *is-a* relationship that inheritance is intended to model (and which clients will expect). You should use composition instead: introduce a member of `B` of type `A`.

Comment: Or divide class A into multiple classes. One class from which B can fully derive. Depends on your situation. At least its a sign that your class design needs a bit more work.

Comment: If I compose A in class B then I probably have to write wrapper functions for every required function of A, which can be quite annoying in case of real life examples.

Comment: @SaifUllah Then maybe you should investigate whether Respect2All's suggestion might work for you.

Comment: @SaifUllah Weigh it up: It's far more annoying to find such a codebase later and realise its original author inappropriately used inheritance everywhere, just to save some typing, as someone who now has to unpick all the unnecessary coupling and vtable overhead (size and time) that said author's laziness introduced. Btw, both "the original author" and "someone" might be the same person; don't underestimate your ability to annoy your future self. I speak from experience as someone who learned the hard way that spamming inheritance creates real overhead and problems when trying to refactor later

Answer (score 4):

You may cheat with private inheritance

```
class B : private A
{
public:
    using A::f1;
    using A::f2;
};
```